# ReactJs - Webpack and environment variable

Tags: reactjs

Im tring to build my ReactApp using an environment variable system.
Following online guides, I've create two different files

```
.env.developtment and .env.production
```

using the syntax for variables:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_SERVER_URL=myapp/
```

During development (using npm start to start the server), development file is loaded perfectly and all variable are stored in process.env global.

Unfortunally after compiling it with webpack, process.env is empty.

Im compiling my code with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.production --progress --env.NODE_ENV=production --colors
```

and in my webpack there is no process.env override (using DefinePlugin is the common mistake).

Following a similar question on this site, I've tried to put this command in the config to avoid any process override:

```
node: {process: false}
```

but with this process.env will be totally undefined instead of empty ( {} ).

Is it possible to use this kind of environment system or .env files are only supported with npm build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the env as an argument does not set the application environment. Said so, I considering you are doing it inside your config. What would set up few env values is the option mode as development or production, which is available on webpack4 (You do -p or -d for the previous versions).

I dont know why you said using webpack.DefinePlugin is a common mistake. I have been using it and it works very well.

In last case, if you are sure you process.env should not be empty I would suggest you to do the syntax process.env["expected_attr"].

Comment: Yeah. Im actually set process.env directly in the webpack production file.